# Python concatenating boolean to string doesn't work

Tags: python, string, boolean, concatenation

As a part of  program I wrote the following method (hidden is a boolean variable). It's located in an object called `Deltext`, which inherits a type called `DelMsg`. `info_msg()` is overriding and using a similar method in its parent type.

```
def info_msg(self):
    info = DelMsg.info_msg(self)
    if self.code == 'l':  # If message is long message
        return info + '#' + str(len(self.content)) + '#' + str(self.hidden)
    elif self.code == 'm':  # If message is snap message
        return info + '#' + str(self.timeout) + '#' + self.content
    else:  # If message is a normal message
        return info + '#' + self.content + '#' + str(self.hidden)
```

But every time I call the method (from the object instance) it displays an error: `TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'bool' objects`, and says the error is in the last line, even though `hidden` is parsed to string.

Is there any way to solve this without using conditionals?

Comment: check the type of the other two variables using type(...), if one of them is boolean, apply str(..) on it as well.

Comment: add str() for all in the return statement

Comment: you can cast `content` and `info` to str without the check if you expect it to be boolean or any other format than string.

Comment: I tired casting the others (though both are string) but it displayed the same error

Comment: Could you post more of your code? Are you sure that the error occurs in this line?

Comment: I added the full method now, the whole class is pretty long, thanks

Comment: For some reason (I have no idea why because I changed nothing) it works now. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you can proceed to debug your code:

1. check the type of the variables:

Edit you code to include the following `print(type(variable))`

```
def info_msg(self):
    print(type(info))
    print(type(self.content))
    return info + '#' + self.content + '#' + str(self.hidden)
```

Then, run the program and see which other variable is boolean.

2. add `str(...)` to the boolean variables

At most, all variables will be of type boolean, so you can edit your code as follows:

```
def info_msg(self):
    return str(info) + '#' + str(self.content) + '#' + str(self.hidden)
```

---

An other option is to use `str.format`, which will take care of casting the variables to string for you:

```
def info_msg(self):
    return "{0}#{1}#{2}".format(info, self.content, self.hidden)
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably `info` or `content` are boolean too. You can overcome this with

```
def info_msg(self):
    return str(info) + '#' + str(self.content) + '#' + str(self.hidden)
```

Comment: I already tried doing this, though both of them are strings, and it kept displaying the same message

Comment: You must be missing something. I've tried this code with all of the items as boolean, and it worked. Wait, I updated it to match class instance